# populate List<things> in reflected external dll class

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reflection, system.reflection

Forgive me for just grasping these terms, I'm on the edge of my C# knowledge here and need to ask for guidance.

I have a DLL which includes two classes and a form (additional class)  one of the classes workitems has public (string name, int id).

```
// in the DLL:
public class workitems {
     public string name {get;set;}
     public int id{get;set;}
}
```

The workhorse class has a variable used in several functions

```
// in the DLL:
public class workhorse {
    List<workitems> WorkLoad = new List<workitems>();

    public function DoThings() {   ..... stuff ...... }
}
```

In another program, I need to call this dll (I assume via reflection).  I've tried

```
 // in a separate C# script that needs to call this via reflection
 Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(thedll);
```

but I can't figure out how to load workitems into the variable, and then call a function from the dll with those workitems...  I'm getting confused with type/class/methodinfo/.GetType...  any guidance would be appreciated.

From the program that has to call the dll file I need do something like :

```
otherdll.workload.add( stuff )

otherdll.DoThings(); (which uses the workload from that class)
```

Comment: I am curious as to why you would state: " I need to call this dll (I assume via reflection)".  Why not reference the dll directly?  There may be a good reason, but your question implies that you picked the most difficult way due to lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code assumes, that you have already your assembly and that `Workload` is a Field, not property:

```
//Get workhorse TypeInfo
var type = asm.ExportedTypes.Single(t => t.Name == "workhorse");
// Create instance of workhorse
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
// Get FieldInfo WorkLoad
var prop = type.GetField("WorkLoad");
// Get object workhorse.WorkLoad
var list = prop.GetValue(obj);
// Get MethodInfo for Add method
var method = prop.FieldType.GetMethod("Add");
// Call it with new object
method.Invoke(list, new [] { (object)new workitems()});
// Get DoThings methodinfo
var doThings = type.GetMethod("DoThings");
// call it without parameters
doThings.Invoke(obj, new object[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I am following except for: How do I create & set the values in the { (object)new workitems() }

I am trying 

 WorkLoadItemType.GetProperty("email").SetValue(obj, "test"+i);  

But not getting anywhere

Comment: @DanFlood is email a property? If it is a fielt you should call WorkLoadItemType.GetField("email")

Comment: AHA!  Thank you it just sunk in.  Wonderful thank you for your assistance!!

Comment: @DanFlood I thought you do have it somewhere else.  You should than really do the same shit with it: find type with  asm.ExportedTypes.Single(t => t.Name == "workitems"); create instance with Activator.CreateInstance, find properties by name and fill it per SetValue. Are you really couldn't just reference the dll in your project? :)